# Push item to associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've been trying to push an item to an associative array like this:

```
$new_input['name'] = array(
    'type' => 'text', 
    'label' => 'First name', 
    'show' => true, 
    'required' => true
);
array_push($options['inputs'], $new_input);
```

However, instead of 'name' as the key in adds a number. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: It is not possible push an array into another array. I've tried all this options and the merge just added the array. I solved my problem with a Class.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

```
$options['inputs']['name'] = $new_input['name'];
```

Answer (score 76):

Instead of **[array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)**, use **[array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)**

It will merge two arrays and combine their items in a single array.

**Example Code** -

```
$existing_array = array('a'=>'b', 'b'=>'c');
$new_array = array('d'=>'e', 'f'=>'g');

$final_array=array_merge($existing_array, $new_array);
```

Its returns the resulting array in the final_array. And results of resulting array will be -

```
array('a'=>'b', 'b'=>'c','d'=>'e', 'f'=>'g')
```

Please review this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), to be aware of possible problems.

Comment: actually it should be
$existing_array = array('a'=>'b', 'b'=>'c');
$new_array = array('d'=>'e', 'f'=>'g');

$result = array_merge($existing_array, $new_array);

Comment: well it is a common sense to collect output. I was just giving the idea. Regards

Answer (score 25):

This is a cool function

```
function array_push_assoc($array, $key, $value){
   $array[$key] = $value;
   return $array;
}
```

Just use

```
$myarray = array_push_assoc($myarray, 'h', 'hello');
```

[Credits & Explanation](http://jaswanttak.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/php-associative-array-push/)

Answer (score 8):

i use `php5.6`

**code**:

```
$person = ["name"=>"mohammed", "age"=>30];

$person['addr'] = "Sudan";

print_r($person)
```

**output**

```
Array( ["name"=>"mohammed", "age"=>30, "addr"=>"Sudan"] )
```

Answer (score 7):

WebbieDave's solution will work.  If you don't want to overwrite anything that might already be at 'name', you can also do something like this:

`$options['inputs']['name'][] = $new_input['name'];`

Comment: This doesn't work if you don't want to keep everything associative, e.g. without pushing other numbered arrays in between.  Have a  look at @Steven H below

Answer (score 5):

If `$new_input` may contain more than just a 'name' element you may want to use `array_merge`.

```
$new_input = array('name'=>array(), 'details'=>array());
$new_input['name'] = array('type'=>'text', 'label'=>'First name'...);
$options['inputs'] = array_merge($options['inputs'], $new_input);
```

Answer (score 3):

Curtis's answer was very close to what I needed, but I changed it up a little.

Where he used:

```
$options['inputs']['name'][] = $new_input['name'];
```

I used:

```
$options[]['inputs']['name'] = $new_input['name'];
```

Here's my actual code using a query from a DB:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $dtlg_array[]['dt'] = $row['dt'];
    $dtlg_array[]['lat'] = $row['lat'];
    $dtlg_array[]['lng'] = $row['lng'];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just change few snippet(use array_merge function):-

```
  $options['inputs']=array_merge($options['inputs'], $new_input);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_input = array('type' => 'text', 'label' => 'First name', 'show' => true, 'required' => true);
$options['inputs']['name'] = $new_input;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to do this:

If the array $arr_options contains the existing array.

```
$arr_new_input['name'] = [
    'type' => 'text', 
    'label' => 'First name', 
    'show' => true, 
    'required' => true
];

$arr_options += $arr_new_input;
```

Warning: $arr_options must exist.
if $arr_options already has a ['name'] it wil be overwritten.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try.

```
$options['inputs'] = $options['inputs'] + $new_input;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use array_merge($array1, $array2) to merge the associative array.
Example:

```
$a1=array("red","green");
$a2=array("blue","yellow");
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => red [1] => green [2] => blue [3] => yellow )
```