# PHP - add further data inside a specific array key whilst keeping the existing data

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array like this:

```
$data[0] = ['a' => 'b'];
$data[1] = ['c' => 'd'];
$data[2] = ['e' => 'f'];
```

How do I add further data inside a specific key of the array whilst keeping the existing data, e.g.

```
$data[0] = ['a' => 'b'];
$data[1] = ['c' => 'd', 'xx' => 'zz']; // New data has been added here.
$data[2] = ['e' => 'f'];
```

How do I add things to `$data[1]` for example?

I've read the following but these don't seem to be the answer:

- [Push item to associative array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206020/push-item-to-associative-array-in-php)
- [How to push both value and key into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121548/how-to-push-both-value-and-key-into-array)
- [Insert new item in array on any position in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php)

I've looked at methods like `array_combine()`, `array_push()` and `array_merge()` but cannot seem to do this. Apologies if this is an obvious question but I have tried to look up the things above and can't figure it out.

Comment: this one should work, no? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php

Comment: No it doesn't. `array_splice($data, 1, 0, ['xx'=>'zz']);`?

Comment: You posted links to some opinions you have found on [so]. But have you read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)? Your problem is described in the ["Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) and ["Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) sections.

Comment: Please post some of your code to see how you are doing it then we can suggest you where it went wrong..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to doing it is this:

```
$data[1]['xx'] = 'zz';
```

Here is another one:

```
$data[1] += ['xx' => 'zz'];
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. For some reason I was looking into `array_` methods which are probably not even required.

Comment: Happy to help. If this solved your question, please consider marking as answer to close this question. TY

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by simple foreach just pass array by reference using `&` in foreach

```
$data[0] = ['a' => 'b'];
$data[1] = ['c' => 'd'];
$data[2] = ['e' => 'f'];


foreach($data as $k => &$n){

if($k == 1) $n['xx'] = 'zz';

}
print_r($data);
```